# Getting at custom attributes in Magento2 - Does it really require a new module?

Tags: magento2, attributes

I have created a custom attribute so we can mark products as either "Best Seller", "Customer Favourite" or "Express Service".

I want to pull this information through to the category pages, so I can show a small icon in the top right of each product that has this customer attribute set.

In Magento 1 this was as simple as using the `addAttributeToSelect` method.

However, everything I can see for Magento 2 tells me I need to create a new module and extend existing core code just to achieve the same thing.

Is this correct? Is there no easier way of getting at custom attributes?

---

If it is correct can somebody explain the logic to me behind this decision making process. Why make a common customizable feature so complex to get at in comparason in the new version of Magento?

Comment: In magento 2 there is `attribute.xml`

Comment: ...keep going...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will require new module.

Try this code replacing your attributes:

Create `catalog_attributes.xml` in `etc` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="catalog_category">
        <attribute name="name"/>
        <attribute name="is_active"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

This code will take attribute from **Cart -> Quote -> Order -> Invoice -> Shipment -> Credit memo**